# plone dexterity inject behavior field after description field

Tags: plone, dexterity, plone-4.x

I'm trying to inject a field from a behavior directly after description, before the content types own fields (non-behavior-based fields).

```py
form.order_after(myfield = 'IBasic.description')
```

does not work - the field still shows up after the non-behavior fields.

```py
form.order_before(myfield = '*')
```

works, but of course puts the field completely at the top.

```py
form.order_before(myfield = '*')
form.order_after(myfield = 'IBasic.description')
```

the field is still at the top.

What did I miss?

```py
form.order_before(myfield = 'first_field_from_ctype')
```

works, but in the nature of things the content types have different fields.

plone.app.dexterity-1.2.1

plone.dexterity-1.1.2

plone 4.2b2

Comment: Can you provide more complete sample of your code? I tried a behavior with "form.order_after(myfield = 'IBasic.description')" with the reported versions without any problems: The behavior field was set correctly between IBasic.description and the content type's own fields.

Answer (score 2):

The `description` field is in the `IDublinCore` behavior, so the proper code is:

```py
form.order_after(myfield = 'IDublinCore.description')
```